# Javascript style guide variable naming conventions for equality

Tags: javascript

I read this somewhere but it escapes me and I cannot remember. What are the common style guides for variable naming conventions for equality? For example:

```
const isPresent = [1,2,3].includes(someVariable)
const isPresent = [1,2,3].includes(1)
// or
const hasOne = [1,2,3].includes(1)

const isEqual = (1 === 1)
const isNotEqual = (1 === 2)
// or
const notEqual = (1 === 2)

const isNoAvailbility = [{...}, {...}].some(slot => slot.time === someTime)
// or
const hasNoAvailbility = [{...}, {...}].some(slot => slot.time === someTime)
// or
const noAvailbility = [{...}, {...}].some(slot => slot.time === someTime)
// or
const notAvailbile = [{...}, {...}].some(slot => slot.time === someTime)

const hasMessages = sentMessages.length || receivedMessages.length
```

These are some examples and feel free to edit and add your own examples. The point is, when do you use `is*` and `has*`, or even what is the common style guide (I looked at the Airbnb one and no luck)? Also, what do variables look like for negation of equality when using `is` or `has`.

Comment: You use "is" and "has" when the plain English meaning of those words applies to what the variable is for - I can't think of an example where you could change "is" to "has" without changing the meaning.

Comment: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better home for this question.